# How do I allow anyone to view my files on my network?

Tags: networking, samba, sudo, shared-folders

I have created a little server on Ubuntu 13.10, I've shared certain folders using SAMBA.

On my WINDOWS PC my username and password is the same as the username and password of the server, so I'm assuming that's why I can connect there, but connecting to the server from my brothers pc is a different story.

I have added to /etc/sudoers :

`jinglez ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Thinking that when he try's to map a new network drive, that he then would be able to login as jinglez and the server password, but this didn't work, however when we created a new user account on his pc, with the above info it did, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: samba is a really old technology you should try using something else like a simple network drive attached to your router.

Comment: @Goddard Such a device, besides being costly, will almost always run the same kind of server as Samba (an SMB/CIFS server).

Comment: I don't know what you consider costly, but 50 bucks for no worries and no setup knowledge required it might be worth it.  It would be for me as supporting windows systems is always a headache.

Answer (score 0):

The `sudoers` file is not used by samba to control user access. This will depend on your Samba configuration, but most samba configurations have the line
`security = user` which requires every user to have an account on your Ubuntu server. So you will have to add the user `jinglez` to the system (you can use the `sudo adduser` command to create this).

Once you've added the user to the system, you'll also have to add them to Samba's user list with the `smbpasswd` tool. Finally, to ensure they have permission to read/write the shares, be sure to add them to the same group as your original user and set the directory's group ownership to that. For more instructions you can refer to this answer: [Samba and User Acount Passwords](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153893/samba-and-user-acount-passwords).

Remember to restart your samba service with `sudo service samba restart` to apply.

If you don't want to create a new user account for your brother there are other options (you can set security on the "share" level, or even do advanced stuff like changing the PAM module Samba uses for authentication) but this is the simplest way.